# Определить, является ли введённое число простым

Tags: c++, devc++

Нужно создать программу, которая будет проверять есть ли введенное число простым(С++)

Comment: Раз нужно, создавайте - мы не будем вам в этом мешать!

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой цикл поиска делителей, соответственно, если делитель найден - число признается непростым:

```
bool prime(long long n){ 
    for(long long i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Вам стоит конкретизовать задачу, за какое время требуется решить и с какой точностью. Например, можно использовать тест Ферма - решение будет с некоторой долей вероятности, но чем больше раз Вы прогоните этот тест - тем больше вероятность правильного ответа.

Comment: На больших числах проверять небудут.